# The requested Performance Counter is not a custom counter, it has to be initialized as ReadOnly After installing of .Net Reflector

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, system, .net-reflector

I have installed `.Net Reflector`, after installation `.net` code is not working properly given me two `error`

> 1. Could not load file or assembly
>      'BallyTech.Library.Utilities.XmlSerializers, Version=14.0.0.14,
>      Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>      system cannot find the file specified.
> 2. The requested Performance Counter is not a custom counter, it has to be initialized as ReadOnly

After uninstalled also same issue persist,

Thanks

Comment: code was working fine, after installed reflector , above issue came.

Comment: .Net Reflector may have updated some of the dependent Dlls, you can look for updating your package to older version (assuming via nuget) when it was working.